# How do I add a user to collaborate on a google App Maker project

Tags: google-app-maker

I have started to use **Google App Maker** and would like to collaborate on an app with a colleague, however when I add a user via the share app button (top right) that user does not have the ability to edit, public or preview the project, they are just able to view the project

Answer (score 1):

You made a right first step. App Maker creates its project files in Drive and you can share them like any other files with your colleagues.

The biggest difference with AM projects is that you can grant edit permissions only to people from your domain. Everybody outside the domain will be able only to view the app.

Another AM peculiarity that worth mentioning is that deployments ownership could not be transferred or shared (only deployment's owner can republish it), but deployment owner cannot delete the deployment (only project's owner can delete deployments).

You can find more details by following the link - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app